# Declared a structure variable which is a dynamic array of another structure. Why is the following C++ program being crashed?

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have declared a structure variable which is a dynamic array of another structure but the program crashes every time. Where am I doing wrong? What are the necessary steps to be taken? I am using DEVC++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Project{
    int pid;
    string name;
};

struct employee{
    int eid;
    string name;
    Project *project_list;
};

int main(){
   struct employee e;
   e.eid = 123;
   e.name = "789";
   e.project_list = (Project *)malloc(2 * sizeof(Project));

   e.project_list[0].pid = 100;
   e.project_list[0].name = "Game";
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C++ are not "dynamic", although they can be dynamically allocated. Also, `malloc` is a very bad habit unless you have very specific needs (which this is not the case).

Comment: If you require an dynamically sized list of objects, the first tool to reach for is usually [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Depending on how the list is going to be used (the "access pattern")  one of the other [library containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) may be a better fit, so familiarize yourself with all of them and their common use-cases when you get some free time. `new` you should use sparingly and only when forced. `malloc` is for very low-level work, usually when you are designing your own specialized container.

Comment: Please change `Project *` to `std::vector<Project>` or `std::list<Project>`.  Pointers are nasty to use and should only be used by experienced developers.

Comment: Why does this crash? Because it doesn't use `std::vector<Project>` for its project list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc()` does not initialize compilcated classes properly and shouldn't be used in C++. You should use `new` or `new[]` instead.

```
e.project_list = new Project[2];
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution is working correctly. But If it was C code what would be the solution as there is no new operator?

Comment: @SaubhikPaladhi: If this was C code, you wouldn't be using a `string` class that is assumed to already be initialized. Your bug occurred because you're mixing C constructs and C++ constructs together.

Comment: `string` lives and dies on the successful execution of its constructor to set up the string. Otherwise you just have a `string` sized blob of memory. If you attempt to use this blob, pointers that `string` expect to be safely pointing at valid objects are pointing at <insert deity of choice> knows where. Bookkeeping variables tracking the status of the `string` contain incorrect values. The `string` is unusable as a `string` until it has been formally made into a `string`. See [this documentation on object lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime).

Answer (score 0):

The structure `Project` uses an object of the type `std::string`

```
struct Project{
    int pid;
    string name;
};
```

So first of all you need to include the header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

To create (and to destroy) an object of this type its constructor (and destructor) shall be called. But the C function malloc knows nothing about constructors. Moreover it even does not initialize the allocated memory.

So in these statements

e.project_list[0].pid = 100;
e.project_list[0].name = "Game";

there is an access to objects of the type `std::string` that were not created. Their constructors were not called.

Use the operator new instead of malloc

```
e.project_list = new Project[2];
```